# How to refresh left pane from right pane for Kendo UI Splitter

Tags: kendo-ui

I have an Asp.net MVC application that has a Kendo UI Splitter on a main page (see codes below).  The main page also has a Kendo UI TreeView (see codes below) .  The right hand side pane is called by an MVC partial view and it has a form so users can input data.  The right pane partial view's contents (input form) are rendered by tree node clicking from the left pane.  I would like on the right hand pane form after users click a HTML button (via Ajax POST) to save data to database, the right pane contents **should** be refreshed so the tree will be refreshed, too.  The right hand pane form **should not** refreshed though.  How can I achieve this? Please help. Thanks very much.

Kendo Splitter on the main view page:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Splitter()
    .Name("top")
    .Orientation(SplitterOrientation.Horizontal)
    .Panes(panes =>
    {
        panes.Add()
            .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "leftPane" })
            .Scrollable(true)
            .Collapsible(true)
            .Size("200px")
            .Content(@<div id="treeView" class="demo-section">

                      </div>);
        panes.Add()
            .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "rightPane" })
            .Scrollable(true)
            .Collapsible(true)
            .Content(@<div id="detail-pane">@{Html.RenderPartial("_RightFormPartial");}</div>);
    })
)
```

TreeView on the main page and sits on the left pane is built like:

```
 var _root = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        cache: false,
                        url: "/Employee/AjaxEmployeeList",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { employeeId : _selectedId }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "Id",
                        hasChildren: "HasChildren",
                        expanded: "expanded",
                        parentId: "parentId",
                        ItemType: "ItemType"
                    }
                }
            });

            _tree = $("#treeView").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource: _root,
                dataTextField: "Name",
                loadOnDemand: true, //do NOT recurse with databound to expand nodes               
                dataImageUrlField: "Image",
                dataBound: function (e) {
                    handleTreeDataBound(e);
                },
                select: function (e) {
                    handleTreeNodeSelection(e.node);
                }
            });

            treeViewCtrl = $("#treeView").data("kendoTreeView");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with Splitter but this is how I've been refreshing partial views and invoking a refresh of Kendo controls.

```
 var grid = $("#ProposalGrid").data("kendoGrid");
 grid.dataSource.page(1) or  grid.dataSource.read() (forget if its a method)
```

On some event you'll have your ajax call.

```
<div id="partialSummaryDiv">@{Html.RenderAction("GetSummary", "Order");}</div>

public ActionResult GetContractTotals()
{
   // blah blah
    return PartialView("_OrderContractTotals", octvm);        
}

$.ajax({
url: "/Order/GetContractTotals",
type: "POST",
success: function (result) {
     // refreshes partial view
    $('#partialSummaryDiv').html(result);
  }
});
```

Hope that helps